# Eventos en Javascript desde html o desde script

Tags: javascript, eventos

tengo una duda en cuanto a eventos de JavaScript. 
Cual sería la diferencia entre hacer esto:

```
   <script>
   function mostrarMensaje(){
alert("Hola mensaje desde funcion!");
      }
   </script>
   <input id="clickeable" type="button" value="Hacé click"  onclick="mostrarMensaje()"/>
```

Y esto?

```
 <input id="clickeable" type="button" value="Hacé click">
 <script>
  var target = document.querySelector("#clickeable");
  target.addEventListener('click', mostrarMensaje);

   function mostrarMensaje(){
alert("Hola mensaje desde funcion!");
      }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Todos los browsers aceptan la asignación de `onclick` como propiedad inline, pero puedes gatillar **un solo evento** usando esa propiedad. Si usas en cambio `target.addEventListener` puedes añadir tantos listeners como quieras.

Si usas `onclick` y además `addEventListener` se gatillarán todos en secuencia.

También puedes **sobreescribir** la propiedad `onclick` haciendo `target.onclick=mostrarMensaje`.

```js
function mostrarMensaje(msg){
  alert(msg);
}
function saluda(){
  alert('hola');
}
function despidete(){
  alert('hasta luego');
}

document.querySelector('#saluda').addEventListener('click', saluda);
document.querySelector('#saluda').addEventListener('click', despidete);

document.querySelector('#debiera').onclick=saluda;
```

```html
<input id="clickeable" type="button" value="Muestra Mensaje"  onclick="mostrarMensaje('mensaje')"/>
 
 <input id="saluda" type="button" value="Mensaje, Saludo y Despedida"  onclick="mostrarMensaje('mensaje')"/>
 
  <input id="debiera" type="button" value="Saludo sobreescribe Mensaje"  onclick="mostrarMensaje('mensaje')"/>
```

El único inconveniente de `addEventListener` es que no está soportado en Explorer 8.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad no hay diferencia en cuanto a funcionalidad se refiere, ambos hacen lo mismo, pero si es recomendable y ademas es una buena práctica, hacerlo por script, ya que en el momento que quieras cambiar el nombre a la funcion tienes que cambiarla en mínimo dos sitios, de otra forma desde el script cambias todo lo que necesites sin tocar html.

Sin mencionar que tienes que cargar la funcion del script antes de el html donde se encuentra la llamada onClick, lo ideal es tener todo el javscript al finalde la página y no repartido en medio del códio, simple organización.